# How to call an arraylist from a function to another function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say for example I got the code:

```
def getRoute(getRouteFile):
    getRoutePath = []
    routeFile = open(getRouteFile, "r")
    for routes in routeFile:
        getRoutePath.append(map(ord, routes.split('>')))
    return getRoutePath
```

If I do a function such as which would try and call the items in the getRoutePath array from a function called:

```
def routeCalculation(getRoute,nodeTable, currentNode):
```

How do I call it? I tried doing these:

```
def routeCalculation(getRoute,nodeTable, currentNode):
    route = getRoutePath

def routeCalculation(getRoute,nodeTable, currentNode):
    route = getRoute[getRouthPath]
```

And none seem to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can't see `getRoutePath` from outside `getRoute`, since it's local to the function. However since `getRoute` returns `getRoutePath`, why can't you just call `getRoute`? Regardless it sounds like you need a tutorial, not StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you declare a variable in a function, when you exit the function, the variable is destroyed. Example:

```
a = ""
def function():
   a = "hello"
   b = "hello"

print(a) #prints "hello" because a was declared outside of the function
print(b) #does not print anything
```

This is called "scope", and if you have a problem understanding it, you should search up a tutorial about it. In order to fix your problem move the code `getRoutePath = []` outside of your functions.